# invalid date when trying to change the date format

Tags: javascript, date, mobiscroll

I have a date value and want to format it.

This is the value:

```
Thu Jul 07 2022 01:03:18 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)
```

I want to make this format:

```
console.log(new Date('YYYY-MM-DD h:i:s', dateVal));
```

but I get invalid date.

How can I make it right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the `Date` object's constructor accepts a handful of parameters to set an actual date, there is no parameter to specify in what way the date should be presented.

So:

```
let dateVal="Thu Jul 07 2022 01:03:18 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)";
console.log(new Date('YYYY-MM-DD h:i:s', dateVal));
```

is nonsense as it tries to construct a date from two strings.

What you can do however is call the Date's built-in function `.toLocaleString()` including the `"sv"` locale to get your Date formatted in **YYYY-MM-DD h:m:s** format.

For example:

```js
let dateVal = "Thu Jul 7 2022 01:03:18 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)";
console.log(new Date(dateVal).toLocaleString("sv"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Date` constructor takes only one argument, you can't format a date using it. Do you want exact format you've shown in your question or an ability to use any arbitrary date format? For the first option, the simplest way I see so far is:

```js
let dateVal = 'Thu Jul 17 2022 01:03:18 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)';
let dateObj = new Date(dateVal);
let dateISO = dateObj.toISOString()
let dateFmt = dateISO.slice(0, 10) + ' ' + dateISO.slice(11, 19)
console.log(dateFmt)
```